# replace all values in all columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as below

[image]

I want to make this df binary as follows

[image]

I tried

df[:]=np.where(df>0, 1, 0)

but with this I am losing my df index.
I can try this on all columns one by one or use loop but I think there would be some easy & quick way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert boolean mask by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) to integers:

```
df1 = df.gt(0).astype(int)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) if integers and no negative values:

```
df1 = df.clip(upper=1)
```

Your solution should working with `loc`:

```
df.loc[:] = np.where(df>0, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

of course it is possible by func, it can be done with just operator

```
(df > 0) * 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using numpy:

```
df[df>0]=0
```